# when integrating by parts $\sin (\sqrt x) \, dx$ could you make $u=\sin(\sqrt x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

Could you integrate $\sin \sqrt x \, dx$ by parts and make $u=\sin \sqrt x , du=\frac{\cos \sqrt x}{2 \sqrt x}, dv=dx$ and $v=x$ and then make further substitutions?

Answer (score 3):

With $u=\sin\sqrt x$, you have $x=\arcsin^2u$ and $dx=\dfrac{2\arcsin u\,du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$.

This gives
$$\int\dfrac{2u\arcsin u\,du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}.$$

Not really appetizing.

Comment: Yes, this gets very nasty very fast when you approach this problem with integration by parts.

Answer (score 2):

i hope you mean to evaluate $$\int \sin \sqrt x \, dx $$ by making a change of variable $u = \sqrt x, x = u^2, dx = 2u \, du.$

$$\int \sin \sqrt x \, dx  = \int \sin u 2u \, du = 2 \int u d (-\cos u) \, du =
2 \left( -u\cos u + \int \cos u \, du \right) = 2 \left( -u\cos u + \sin u  + C \right)  $$

Comment: Perfect answer. I was thinking about it too. :)

Comment: DEFINITELY better then Yves' proposed approach.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234: I am not proposing, I am answering the question.